# How to get correct universal timestamp in java if the time is set wrong on the computer?

Tags: java

Is there any way to get the results like in [this](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/) link having wrong date and time set on device?  Thank you.

Comment: If it's not built into the hardware then you'd have to contact some server, and if it were built into the hardware then you'd not have the wrong time on the device.

Comment: Do you mean how to do a NTP request ?

Comment: how would you know the time is wrong if you didn't already have the correct time?

Comment: @Thomas I mean if I intentionally change the data and time on the computer, is there any method in java to get the right UTC (GMT) time without requests to any servers?

Comment: "Without requests to any servers". The answer is "No" (of course!) Unless you're Harry Potter.

Comment: Just as I said: unless the hardware has a built-in high precision timer (like an atomic clock) so that it knows the "correct" time there's no way to do it without contacting any external system. You could avoid having to contact a "server" if your device's timer is radio-controlled but in that case you'd probably not be able to change the system time anyways.

Comment: I feel you have a more basic problem you want to work around with this. If so please elaborate and we might be able to suggest a solution that doesn't require magic ;)

Comment: @Thomas ok :) The problem i am working on is the TOTP algorithm. The thing I was wondering is how would it work if the time on server and the one on the device are not the same. The app "Google Authenticator" does not generate the right code at this case.

Comment: `I was wondering is how would it work if the time on server and the one on the device are not the same.` - this indicates you actually have access to a server so either get and use the server's time (e.g. by calculating a date form the current device time and the difference between device and server time) or do it the other way round, i.e. let the server track the time difference for each device. Some key generation systems I know of do that and adjust the server's view of device time unless the difference is too huge - in which case the server assumes something is fishy.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way<sup>1</sup> ...

Suppose that you have deliberately set the clock 1 minute slow.

Create a file that contains the number 60,000.  When an application wants to find the correct time, it calls `System.getTimeMillis()` to get what the system thinks the time is.  Then reads the number from the file and adds that number to the result of `System.getTimeMillis()`.

Clearly, this is NOT a good idea, but then neither is deliberately setting the system clock incorrectly.  (For a start, if the clock is miss-set, then you will have difficulty syncing it with an external time source like an NTP server.  That means that your system's clock will drift.)

---

> The problem i am working on is the TOTP algorithm. The thing I was wondering is how would it work if the time on server and the one on the device are not the same.

I see.  The answer is that TOTP cannot work if the two clocks are not synchronized to within a small multiple of the timestep.

---

<sup>1 - There's another way too.  Write an application that can do some image processing on a picture of a clock to read the time.  Then hook this up to your computer's video camera, and point the camera at a cuckoo clock hanging on your wall.  Make sure you wind up the clock regularly.  If you want the date as well, point a second video camera at your Dilbert desk calendar.</sup>